# Layout and floating div problems

Tags: html, css, css-float

So, I have this layout looks like this [image: http://puu.sh/8Kkrd.png]

As you can see there, the div is floating/aligned to the right side perfectly but on the left side there's a gap between it, how do I clear the gap?

DIV CSS:

```
.thread-list{
   width: 40%;
   background-color: #fff;
   padding: 10px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:1px;
   border-color:#F0F0F0;
   margin-bottom: 3px;
   margin-right: 10px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   overflow: auto;
   float: left;
}
```

NOTE: The div is showing content dynamically (from database), and I can't make the div in 2 separated columns.

Sorry, if I'm being not clear enough.

Comment: can u create jsfiddle? so that we can easily understand your problem. At present this question is not much clear.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SkLst/

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DLMQk/)**

If you float multiple elements & one of the div has larger height then others, then these types of effect are created (the one you showed in your screenshot).

**Solution 1:**  clear float left from 1st element of each row using `:nth-child(2n+1)` in your case its `..2n..` cuz you have 2 elements in one row.

Add this css in your style-sheet:

```
.thread-list:nth-child(2n+1){
    clear:left;
}
```

**Solution 2:** Solution 1 will align all the div's but there will still be a negative space beneath, if you dont want that then you have to use plugins like **[Masonry Layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**, this effect can not be achieved with pure css.

Comment: @user3629435 check this out i think you are looking for **[Masonry Layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/)**

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't help, clear:left makes the layout look normal http://jsfiddle.net/N6WKz/

but i'll take a look at masonry layout, it seems that it is easier using it, thank you